# Displaying loaded project file name in QGIS title bar when opening via QgsProject.instance().read()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

On Windows, if I open a project in QGIS then the project file name appears in the title bar.

If I do the same thing in PyQGIS using the following code the title bar does not change.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo("C:/FilePath.qgs"))
```

But the project loads fine, I can see my project data and if I click the save button then the file name appears in the title bar.

I was wondering if there was a bridge or some hack needed to get the file name to appear. I need this because my client has similar looking projects and uses the file name to know that my code has loaded the right one for them. Of course I could show it to them another way like in the message bar but seeing as opened projects normally get their file name in the title bar I thought I should be keeping to this 'standard' way of doing it.

Things I've tried...

1. Saving the file via:

   ```
   QgsProject.instance().write()
   ```

Does save the file but doesn't update the title bar.

2. Canvas bridge code

   ```
   from qgis.gui import *
   canvas = QgsMapCanvas()

   bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge( \
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
   ```

Also didn't help.

How can I get the file name to appear in the title bar of QGIS when using .read() ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally in the titlebar, it will read `QGIS 2.18.2` (or whatever version being used).

What I tend to do is to remove this and instead just use the name of the project that's loaded. So instead of reading:

```
QGIS 2.18.2 - MyProject
```

it will simply read:

```
MyProject
```

---

Personal choice but you can edit the title using:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import os

project_path = "C:/FilePath.qgs"

QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(project_path))
iface.mainWindow().setWindowTitle(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(project_path))[0])
#iface.mainWindow().setWindowTitle("QGIS 2.18.2 - " + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(project_path))[0])
```